# JSON schema to enforce array contents

Tags: arrays, json, validation, schema, jsonschema

Hi all and thanks in advance.

I am attempting to create a JSON schema to enforce an array to contain one A and B object and N C objects, where A and B are C objects and N is an integer inclusively between 0 and infinity.

Therefor :

`[A, B]`
`[A, B, C1]`
`[A, B, C1, .., CN]`

Are all **valid**, though :

`[A]`
`[A, C1]`
`[A, C1, .., CN]`

Are **not valid**.

To make clear, A and B must be present. C objects are optional, though you may have as many as you would like.

**C object schemas :**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "C Object",

  "type": "object",
  "required": ["id", "name"],

  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

So a C object is any valid JSON object containing only the properties "id" and "name" where "id" is an integer and "name" is a string.

**A and B object schemas :**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "A Object",

  "type": "object",
  "required": ["id", "name"],

  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["A"]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "B Object",

  "type": "object",
  "required": ["id", "name"],

  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["B"]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

A and B objects differ from C objects in that there name value is enforced. The name value of an A object must be a value contained in the field enum, where enum contains a single value.

**My most complete schema to date is :**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "To Date Solution",
  "description": "So far this is the most complete attempt at enforcing values to be contained within a JSON structure using JSON schemas.",

  "type": "array"
  "items": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "C Object",

        "type": "object",
        "required": ["id", "name"],

        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This enforces that all objects contained within must be of type C, which A and B are, though I am unsure how to enforce that at least single instance of A and B are contained within my array.

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have to be the first two (in that order)?  Or can they appear anywhere in the list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "tuple typing".

If the value of the `items` keyword is an array, then the items in the array data must match up with the schema in the corresponding position.  Additional items (past the last index) are matched by `additionalItems` (or are disallowed if `additionalItems` is `false`).

So, roughly what you want is something like:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/itemTypeA"},
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/itemTypeB"}
    ],
    "additionalItems": {"$ref": "#/definitions/itemTypeC"},
    "definitions": {
        ... actual definitions for A/B/C ...
    }
}
```

If you want to *ensure* that A and B exist, then you simply specify a minimum length using `minItems`, so there are at least two items (which because of "tuple typing", must match up with A and B).

*(This also assumes that A and B are the first items in the array.  If that's not what you want, then it gets a bit more complicated - although there is a [`contains`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/contains-%28v5-proposal%29) keyword proposed for v5 that would handle that neatly.)*

Slightly more detailed live demo:

- [Valid](http://bit.ly/1iN77lR): `[A, B]`
- [Invalid](http://bit.ly/1el9Llx): `[A, C]`
- [Valid](http://bit.ly/1arTROH): `[A, B, C, C]`

Comment: This matches the answer I came to below and is what I implemented to move forward though I am looking for it to be position independent.

Than you though. From this I gained a knowledge of tuple typing and the thought to look at Json Schema v5 :)

Comment: You *can* do [something rather horrible](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7359001) in v4 if you want it to be position independent.  However, I would generally not advise it, as it's hard to read/understand.

Comment: It's also worth noting that with both the v4 hack and the v5 `contains` keyword, the constraint is "at **least** one" - and `additionalItems` does not apply.  For v5, there is [a workaround](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7359101) to specify exactly one.

Comment: Could you link documentation for v5 please?I was unable to locate it.

Comment: The v5 spec is actually still being written, although it's promised very soon.  However, the various proposed keywords are already on the [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/v5-Proposals). They're not guaranteed to all make it, but [`contains`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/contains-(v5-proposal)) is almost certainly in.

Comment: For me, the "$ref"s wouldn't work. Finally, I figured out "$id" was set to something "/foo/bla/", which causes problems. If your refs don't work, check/remove your "$id"!

Answer (score 1):

I have determined a solution that solves my problem, enforcing that A and B are present within the array, though does so positionally, thus requiring the JSON object I am validating to be ordered in some manner.

**Working Schema**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Order dependent solution",

  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "A Object",

      "type": "object",
      "required": ["id", "name"],

      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["A"]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "B Object",

      "type": "object",
      "required": ["id", "name"],

      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["B"]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ],

  "additionalItems": {

    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "C Object",

    "type": "object",
    "required": ["id", "name"],

    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false  
  }

}
```

This JSON schema validates a JSON array containing a A object at index 0, a B object at index 1, and C objects composing all remaining elements. This solution is usable, and allows me to move forward with development, though a order independent solution would be prefered.

Any help is appreciated! :)

PS - These schemas are not optimized, and demonstrate redundancy, which I will remove in the final version by making use of the "id" and "$ref" keyword.

Comment: BTW - you don't need `$schema` in every schema, just the top-level one.

Comment: In face, I believe it is now prohibited!