# JSON Schema draft 4 with unordered array

Tags: arrays, json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I would like to create schema which allows me to add multiple addresses when the following is true:

- 1)Correspondence address must be there
- 2)Residence address must be there
- 3)Other types of addresses could be there
- 4) They can appear in any order

Is this possible to solve with JSON schema? I heard about "contains" in draft 6. But since we are using Altova XML SPY (2018), which is only supporting draft 4, for schema creation, I would like to know how to solve this in draft 4. Are you aware of any good editor for draft 6? 
I read [JSON schema to enforce array contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692765/json-schema-to-enforce-array-contents?rq=1) but cannot find the answer there. I also read https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7359001 which explains how to have "contains" in draft 4, but was unable to apply it to my case. 
So if you can guide me, how to use it for the following schema(which fullfills my requirements except number 4), I would be very thankfull.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Comment describing your JSON Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "addresses": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "Corespondence"
                            ]
                        },
                        "otherData": {}
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "type",
                        "otherData"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "Residence"
                            ]
                        },
                        "otherData": {}
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "type",
                        "otherData"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "additionalItems": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Address"
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "Address": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "Corespondence",
                        "Residence",
                        "Other"
                    ]
                },
                "otherData": {}
            },
            "required": [
                "type",
                "otherData"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

draft-06 has "contains" keyword allowing to test the presence of items matching the schema in the array.

Alternatively, instead of heterogenous array you could use a map with difference address types defined in different properties, so your data could be:

```
{
  addresses: {
    correspondence: {/*...*/},
    residence: {/*...*/}
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please outline how to do it with a map? Basic JSON structure would be enough....or link to some documentation...Thank  you

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I see what you meant. Unfortunately the data structure is already defined - as described above(type of the address is an attribute inside Address object). So, do you think my requirements cannot be fulfilled without using 'contains' ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `contains` was added to draft-06 is that it is not possible to accomplish the same thing with draft-04 keywords.

There are several implementations supporting draft-06 on the software page: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html